# Updated Magento, still see old version in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect-manager

I just did a upgrade using Mage_All_Latest in the Magento Connect Manager. 
it now shows 1.9.3.2 (stable) but the version at the bottom of all the admin pages shows ver 1.9.1.0. Is this anything I need to fix or worry about?

Comment: Have you changed Mage.php ?

Comment: php cached? check version in `app/Mage.php`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

For some reason, the upgrade did not replace app/Mage.php which can be a typical result if you use Magento Connect to do the upgrade.

It probably failed to upgrade other module content as well.

Otherwise it's reinstall time via other means. This type of stuff is why I always do a manual install direct from the downloadable tar.gz file.

**Solution 2 :**

So I fixed it like this. Went to website root in SSH and did the following:

```
chmod +x mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage sync
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

At step './mage mage-setup .' it thrown error "channel-add: Channel 'community' already exist!" which I think is ok.

After all I've logged to admin backend and it shows Magento v.1.9.2.0 now. Cleaned caches and once again did check for upgrades in Magento connect manager and it shows everything is up to date.